# $(E, \| \cdot\|)$ is Banach where $E = \mathcal{C}^1([-1,1])$ and $\|f\| = \|f\|_\infty + \|f'\|_\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I'm working on a exercice where I need to show that, for

- $E = \mathcal{C}^1([-1,1])$
- with the norm $\|f\| = \|f\|_\infty +
     \|f'\|_\infty$,

$(E, \| \cdot\|)$ is Banach.

I have already shown that $(\mathcal{C^0}([-1,1]),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is Banach and that $(E, \| \cdot\|)$ is a normed vector space. I am mostly interested in proving its completeness. I have already seen a different proof but I was wondering if the following is correct.

---

Here is what I have:

for a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq0} \subset E$, there exist

- $f \in \mathcal{C^0}([-1,1])$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ and
- $g \in \mathcal{C^0}([-1,1])$ such that $f_n'\rightarrow g$

when $n\rightarrow \infty $ since $(f_n)$ and $(f_n')$ are both in $\mathcal{C^0}([-1,1])$.
**So I want to show that $f' = g$.**

Let $t\in[-1,1]$ and $\epsilon >0$, then by the convergence $\exists N$ such that

- $\epsilon>|f_n'(t)-g(t)| = \Bigl|\frac{f_n(t+h)-f_n(t)-R(h)}{h} - g(t)\Bigr|$
  $\forall n \geq N$
  and for some small enough $h$ .

and where $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{R(h)}{h} = 0$.

If we let $n \rightarrow \infty$ (convergence of $f_n$ plus continuity of modulus), then we obtain that
$\epsilon>\Bigl|\frac{f(t+h)-f(t)-R(h)}{h} - g(t)\Bigr|$ and then by letting $h \rightarrow 0 $ we obtain that $\epsilon>|f'(t) - g(t)|$.

Since $\epsilon$ and $t$ were arbitrarily chosen, we have that $f' = g$ and with a couple of extra steps we can go on to conclude that the space is complete.

I am unsure about the step where $h \rightarrow 0$. Is that legal? If not, could you please provide some explanation as to why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you mean $h\to0$?

Comment: @Darsen, yes, small typo. I've just corrected it. Thanks

Comment: $R(h)$ is $n$-dependent, so you must ensure that $\lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{R_n(h)}{h}=0$. This basically amounts to a limit-exchange argument

Comment: Oh okay so therein lies the problem...Thanks @Caffeine! Is there some sort of continuity that I could exploit to swap the limits ? The solution presented by our tutor  was quite different. I guess that's the reason why.

Comment: Since $f'$ is continuous and uniformly convergent, using integrals gives a very easy proof of the result, without any need to exchange the two limits

Comment: Okay, so I think this is the same result as presented in classroom. I was curious to know whether there was another way about it. Thank you!